# Socket connect isn't working, and I don't receive an error message

Tags: python

So I've been working on getting multiple python files to communicate, with one of those files acting as the server. The goal here is to be able to control all PCs running an instance of the "Client" script to connect to the "Server" script, from which I can control each PC.

Since I'm testing all of this on a single PC at the moment, I run an instance of the server, and the client script. Normally, I'd start up an instance of the "Server" script, than an instance of the "Client" script. When the "Client" script talks to the "Server" script for the first time, the "Server" script should show the IP that belongs to the PC that's running the "Client" script, but it isn't.

Here's my server script:

```
import socket,subprocess,time
print ("This is the server speaking")

def Main():
    host = "0.0.0.0"
    port = 2346

    s = socket.socket()
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind((host,port))

    s.listen(10)
    conn,addr = s.accept()
    print ("connection from: " + str(addr))
    while True:
        message=input(" -> ")
        while message !='q':
            conn.send(message.encode())
            data=conn.recv(16834).decode()
            print ("Received data from server: " + data)

            message = input (" -> ")
    conn.close()
    time.sleep(5)
    Main()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

And this is my client script:

```
import socket,time,os
import subprocess

def Main():
        host = '127.0.0.1'
        port = 2346    
        conn = socket.socket()
        conn.connect((host,port))
        while True:
            #data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
            data = conn.recv(16384).decode()
            if not data:
                    break
            print ("from connected  user: " + str(data))
            if data == "tasklist":
                batcmd="tasklist"
                result = subprocess.check_output(batcmd, shell=True)
                data = str(result)
                conn.send(data.encode())
            elif "taskkill" in data:
                pid = data[9:]
                print (pid)
                try:
                    batcmd="taskkill /IM %s /F" % (pid)
                    result = subprocess.check_output(batcmd, shell=True)
                    data = str(result)
                    conn.send(data.encode())
                except:
                    pass
            elif "ls" in data:
                dirs = data[3:]
                try:
                    x = os.listdir(dirs)
                    data = str(x)
                    conn.send(data.encode())
                except:
                    data = "Dir. " +dirs+ " does not exist"
                    conn.send(data.encode())
            data = str(data)
            print ("sending: " + str(data))
            conn.send(data.encode())
        conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

The "if" and "elif" statements in the middle are really just for my current commands. I'm fairly certain that the problem must lie somewhere in the server script, or the top of the client script.

The main issue here is that when I run an instance of the client script, nothing is printed on the server script's side. If anyone could help, that would be well appreciated.

Note: I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: When a client connects, your server goes into an infinite loop talking to that client forever, so it's never going to see any other client try to connect.

Comment: I only need the one client to connect at the moment, not multiple ones.

Comment: ... Mostly because I'm working out all of the commands.

Comment: I open a new terminal, run the server, open another new terminal, and run the client. The server prints out `connection from: ('127.0.0.1', 49903)`, and then prints the `input` prompt. The client doesn't display anything. Is that not what you're seeing?

Comment: That's EXACTLY what it's supposed to do! Why would it not work for me?...

Comment: It must not be a problem with the scripts then...

Comment: Can anyone think of any reason why this works on another's pc, but not mine?